# Cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL using a not root account from GAE

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm having a problem with trying to stablish a database connection with an user that's not root. I mean I have defined the following user at my database.

dev@host

I try to connect the way indicated here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/, but I get a truly strange error, I've set the application to display what error is the one that doesn't allow to connect with that user and I get this:

java.sql.SQLException:Access denied for user 'dev@host'@'localhost'.

I wonder where it can get that localhost from... I've also tried to change the name of the user to dev'@'host but it keeps on the localhost issue.

If I connect with root, not inputting any user or password it connects properly, but I need the application to be connected by users with less privileges.

Any idea what I can be doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As mentioned below, could you check what you have set up under 'Authorization' and 'Access Control', as well as post details of how you are actually making the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Check this page…you need to set up permissions…

https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/access-control?hl=pt

Are you using a mySql client? Did you manage to add an authorized IP address?

Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't post comments below posts before you hit 50 rep.